# Google maps does not show up when uploading it

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

So i tried a lot of suggestions online, saw a lot of people have similar problems with it.
So i signed the app for release, generated to keys( understood is better to add to the google maps api release.xml a different key from the debug one) and added the sha1 for the release on console google play after my keystore, still no results.

The only thing i observed and may be a solving is when i am trying to run the app i get the error(1) that states my app is not signed. And found online that i need to go to project structure and sign it -> build types->release -> chose my config. but after i press ok the config dissapears and gradle(3) remains unchanged. ( Would like to mention that in the Project structure i get 2 errors about my SDK/ NDK(2) that says their location should`t contain white spaces but i understood there is no real problem)

Please help, i`ve tried everything i could find.

[image: (1)]

[image: (2)]

[image: (3)]

Thank you, 
Daud.

Comment: maybe you can show us your gradle configuration? And maybe you can also post these two errors?

Comment: I just added the errors and the gradle configuration

Comment: See my answer and beside that, did you specify the API Key in manifest file? `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>`

Comment: Yes, the only difference is that my android name says com.google.android.geo.API_KEY . Do i need to change it? I think i put it this way because of a tutorial, my map is a styled map. I did it with Maps Platform Styling Wizard

Comment: Did you try to sign your application?

Comment: Yes, uploaded and released to my account as Alpha. The app works good, the only problem is when you press on the google map activity the only thing that appears is a white screen. But when testing on the emulator it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can define your signingConfigs in your gradle file manually?

Something like this:

```
signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'YourKeyAlias'
            keyPassword 'YourKeyPass'
            storeFile file('./yourKeyStore.jks')
            storePassword 'yourStorePass'
        }
    }
```

and specify your configuration in buildTypes:

```
release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            ...
        }
```